# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Not sure if this belongs here, but I had an answer with [47 upvotes](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/17875/when-will-the-sun-end-all-human-life-on-earth/17876#17876), and it was just deleted an hour ago with no comment. I lost 470 rep from that. Could someone explain how it broke the rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was an accident. I apologize for the mistake. I have undeleted your answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks

Comment: Somehow it was deleted again. I undeleted it.

Comment: Er, it still says it's deleted.

Comment: Refresh........